# Sending Arabic data to database by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a text box named "rep" that sends Arabic data to a PHP file using jQuery. The problem is that the database encoding is `latin1_swedish_ci`, not UTF8 and I cannot change it because it'll cause a problem in viewing the previous data.

Here is my code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(function() {
$("input[name='rep']").each(function(i) {
    $(this).change(function($mainElement) {
            var rep_name = $(this).val();
            var item_id = $(this).attr('id');
var request = $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "inc/rep.php",
  data: { rep: rep_name, id: item_id }
});
request.done(function( msg ) {
                $('#dd').html(msg);
  });
        });
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15" />
<?php
include "config.php";

if($_POST["rep"]){
$rep = $_POST["rep"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
$mysqltable="items";

    $q = mysql_query("UPDATE " . $mysqltable . " SET rep='".$rep."' WHERE id=".$id);
(".$id.",'".$rep."')");

    echo ($q)? "done ".$_POST["rep"] : 'failed';

}
```

I want to save the sent value to the database but I found it saved in strange letters 
please advice how to use the correct encoding.

Comment: `latin1_swedish_ci` is the collation, not the encoding. Nevertheless, without changing the db's encofing, you wont be able to store characters that are not present in `latin1` as it is the european charset and not the arabic: http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/iso8859-1.html. The only solution I can think of is to encode the data as base64 (e.g.) but that will make the data unusable by the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that works for me was add these two lines to my php file, and convert my tables in mysql to utf8_unicode_ci:

`mysqli_set_charset($conn_i, "utf8");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`